# specify usage of minimized files in rails 3.2 application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

So I'm upgrading from bootstrap 2 to 3 in my rails 3.2 application. I followed the documentation and added the js, css, and fonts to app/vendor. However I added both the regular and the .min css and .js as per the documentation.

My question is do I need both the .min and the regular and where in my rails app does it specify if it uses the .min js and the .min css ?

Also when installing an external plugin (do I just use the .min js and css or copy both and specify which one to use somewhere else in the app?)

Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one of them. They do essentially have the same content, only the `.min` version is with removed whitespace etc. So when you add both, you add all the css/js twice!

I normally take the un-minified version which is easier for debugging. When going to production, one can set the assets pipeline to minify all js/css:

```
#config/production.rb
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
```

So you get essentially the same content you'd get including the `.min` files in production, but can use the full source code in development.

Also, instead of putting the bootstrap files into your `assets` folder manually, you can also use the [Rails Bootstrap](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) gem.